# Using Ignite TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder in a purely IPv6 environment

Tags: kubernetes, ignite, ipv6

Are  there any know issues with running the org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder a purely IPv6 environment? I looked [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/network-configuration) and it mentions there may be issues with clusters becoming detached but does not offer any specifics.  Any information would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any IPv6 problems *per se*, so if your network is configured correctly I would expect it to work.

The problem we typically see when IPv6 is enabled is that it's possible to route to the IPv4 address but *not* the IPv6 address -- which is why setting preferIPv4Stack works.